# asp.net core identity simpleinjector register applicationusermanager

Tags: domain-driven-design, asp.net-core-identity

i'm try isolation ASP.NET Core Identity version 1.1.2, architecture DDD and creating a CrossCutting layer to create a classlib for aspnet core identity , and i using SimpleInjector 4.0.8 for my IoC, so i create a class ApplicationUserManager and ApplicationSignInManager, but i'm cannot register this class in the simlpleinjector container

**ApplicationUserManager**

```
public class ApplicationUserManager : UserManager<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationUserManager(IUserStore<ApplicationUser> store,
        IOptions<IdentityOptions> optionsAccessor,
        IPasswordHasher<ApplicationUser> passwordHasher,
        IEnumerable<IUserValidator<ApplicationUser>> userValidators,
        IEnumerable<IPasswordValidator<ApplicationUser>> passwordValidators,
        ILookupNormalizer keyNormalizer, IdentityErrorDescriber errors,
        IServiceProvider services,
        ILogger<UserManager<ApplicationUser>> logger)
            : base(store, optionsAccessor, passwordHasher, userValidators, passwordValidators, keyNormalizer, errors, services, logger)
    {
        // My configurations stuffs were...
    }
}
```

and the class **ApplicationSignInManager**

```
public class ApplicationSignInManager : SignInManager<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationSignInManager(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager,
        IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor,
        IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<ApplicationUser> claimsFactory,
        IOptions<IdentityOptions> optionsAccessor,
        ILogger<SignInManager<ApplicationUser>> logger)
            : base(userManager, contextAccessor, claimsFactory, optionsAccessor, logger)
    { }

    // TODO: bug com tipo de retorno IdentityResult para ClaimsPrincipal
    //public override Task<ClaimsPrincipal> CreateUserPrincipalAsync(ApplicationUser user)
    //{
    //    return user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync((ApplicationUserManager)UserManager);
    //}
}
```

and i try register this class in **BootStrapper.cs** like this

```
public static void RegisterServices(Container container)
    {
        // Infra.Data App Context
        // IdentityAppDbContext
        container.RegisterSingleton(() => 
        {
            var options = new DbContextOptions<IdentityAppDbContext>();
            return new IdentityAppDbContext(options);
        });

        // NetCore Identity
        container.RegisterSingleton<ApplicationUserManager>();
        container.RegisterSingleton<ApplicationSignInManager>();
        container.RegisterSingleton<IUserStore<ApplicationUser>>(() =>
        {
            var options = new DbContextOptions<IdentityAppDbContext>();
            return new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new IdentityAppDbContext(options));
        });
        container.Register(() => (IOptions<IdentityOptions>)new IdentityOptions());
        container.RegisterSingleton<IPasswordHasher<ApplicationUser>>(() => new PasswordHasher<ApplicationUser>());

    }
```

but when i run the aaplication return erros says i need registre IOptions, IPasswordHasher and other params in contructors class, the queston is, how can'i register this class?

Comment: Why not use the built-in IoC container that asp.net core provides out of the box?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection

Comment: i think this does not resolve my case, because in use a webapi and a webmvc for layoutin this case i need configure em this two solutions this native IoC from asp.net core, another ideia??

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar requirement: my application needs to interact with identity (it's basically about human resources, that might have a user account on their own or not), and after struggling a long time with with various issues having identity in the framework container, I was trying to configure simple injector to provide all identity services. Call it crazy, but this is how it works (SimpleInjector 4.0 and ASP.Net Identity Core 2.0.1):

This is the "ConfigureServices" part:

```
// identity options are provided from outside, allowing configuration of the framework
container.RegisterSingleton<IOptions<IdentityOptions>>(new OptionsWrapper<IdentityOptions>(identityOptions));

// we rely on BCrypt instead of the default PBKDF2 hashing algorithm
container.Register<IPasswordHasher<MepUser>>(()=>new BCryptPasswordHasher(bcryptOptions));

// forwarding the framework logger to our own logging framework
container.Register<Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILoggerFactory, FrameworkToBackendFxLoggerFactory>();
container.Register(typeof(Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger<>), typeof(Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Logger<>));

// identity store = a specific Entity Framework Core  DbContext, getting mapped into a specific db scheme
container.RegisterSingleton(identityDbContextOptions);
container.Register<MepIdentityDbContext>();

// UserStore<T> und RoleStore<T> both require a DbContext (no IdentityDbContext, neither a generic TDbContext)
// via constructor, but the container only knows about MepIdentityDbContext so we have to wire it manually
container.Register<IUserStore<MepUser>>(() => new UserStore<MepUser>(
                                                container.GetInstance<MepIdentityDbContext>(),
                                                container.GetInstance<IdentityErrorDescriber>()));
container.Register<IRoleStore<IdentityRole>>(() => new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(
                                                container.GetInstance<MepIdentityDbContext>(),
                                                container.GetInstance<IdentityErrorDescriber>()));

// framework internal services
container.Register<IdentityErrorDescriber>();
container.Register<ILookupNormalizer, UpperInvariantLookupNormalizer>();
container.Register<IPasswordValidator<MepUser>, PasswordValidator<MepUser>>();
container.Register<IUserValidator<MepUser>, UserValidator<MepUser>>();
container.Register<IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<MepUser>, UserClaimsPrincipalFactory<MepUser>>();
container.Register<IRoleValidator<IdentityRole>, RoleValidator<IdentityRole>>();

// ASP.Net Core Identity violates a design decision of SimpleInjector: The API clearly differentiates the registration of collections
// https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/decisions.html#the-api-clearly-differentiates-the-registration-of-collections
// By registering IEnumerables of those violating services with a simple wrapping single item array, Identity is happy
container.Register<IEnumerable<IUserValidator<MepUser>>>(() => new[] { container.GetInstance<IUserValidator<MepUser>>() });
container.Register<IEnumerable<IRoleValidator<IdentityRole>>>(() => new[] { container.GetInstance<IRoleValidator<IdentityRole>>() });
container.Register<IEnumerable<IPasswordValidator<MepUser>>>(() => new[] { container.GetInstance<IPasswordValidator<MepUser>>() });

// Role and UserManager reflect the API surface of the whole ASP.Net Core Identity framework
container.Register<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>();
// UserManagerShim is omitting (=nulling) the IServiceProvider parameter of UserManager<T>
container.Register<UserManager<MepUser>, UserManagerShim>();
```

and this needs to be done during "Configure", otherwise password reset and other two factor token stuff won't work (runtime error, although the container was verified)

```
// if you eagerly instantiate a provider instance that is considered being a singleton and
// put it into the respective field in the TokenProviderDescriptor and list it in the option's
// provider map, ASP.Net Core Identity will use this one instead of asking the IServiceProvider 
// instance injected into UserManager<T> (that we do not do, because it is bad design. Instead, 
// we just stuff null in there)
identityOptions.Tokens.ProviderMap[TokenOptions.DefaultProvider] =
        new TokenProviderDescriptor(typeof(DataProtectorTokenProvider<MepUser>))
        {
            ProviderInstance = new DataProtectorTokenProvider<MepUser>(
                    dataProtectionProvider, 
                    new OptionsWrapper<DataProtectionTokenProviderOptions>(new DataProtectionTokenProviderOptions()))
        };

identityOptions.Tokens.ProviderMap[TokenOptions.DefaultEmailProvider] =
        new TokenProviderDescriptor(typeof(EmailTokenProvider<MepUser>)) {
                ProviderInstance = new EmailTokenProvider<MepUser>()
        };
```

Although there appears `AspNetCore` in the namespace definition, nothing is dependent on ASP.Net Core hosting, actually. The only dependency to the "outside world" are the options (POCOs) and an implementation of `IDataProtectionProvider`, that will use the `KeyRing` in ASP.Net scenarios, but can also be satisfied using the `EphemeralDataProtectionProvider` in tests.

Caveat: `SignInManager<T>` is not being injected. This class is a total mess, depending on the whole world, so I rewrote it basically matching my requirements. You also loose lots of the configuration flexibility regarding token providers. But however, in my case it's something you decide once at design time, so I am fine with it.